# No suitable ARIMA models found

Tags: r, arima

I have the following [data](https://pastebin.com/gG157Egz) and trying to run [arima_standard and arima_fourier](https://pastebin.com/Vd2bTw29). I am backtesting so I am running the forecast for a couple of dates. In this case I am running it as of September 2018, hence the training data is between `2016-01-29` and `2017-09-30` and the testing data is between `2017-10-01` and `2018-09-30`.

```
    how_many_weeks_test <- 52
    how_many_days_test <- 365
    temp_fcst_train_data <- head(temp_fcast_data, -1 * how_many_days_test)
    temp_fcst_test_data <-  tail(temp_fcast_data, how_many_days_test)
```

Column `j` is a variable `var` in data file, there are multiple variables I am forecasting but only this one has these issuse hence I provided the data only for this one.

```
temp_xreg_cols <- c(names(temp_fcst_train_data[, grepl("special_events",names(temp_fcst_train_data))]),  paste("day_fluct_", j, sep = ''))
  temp_xreg_cols2 <- names(temp_fcst_train_data[, grepl("month",names(temp_fcst_train_data)) | grepl("wday",names(temp_fcst_train_data)) | grepl("special_events",names(temp_fcst_train_data))])
  temp_model1 <- arima_fourier_train(train = temp_fcst_train_data, test = temp_fcst_test_data, column = j, freq = 364)
  temp_model2 <- arima_standard_train(train = temp_fcst_train_data, test = temp_fcst_test_data, column = j , freq = 364, xreg_cols = temp_xreg_cols)
  temp_model3 <- arima_standard_train(train = temp_fcst_train_data, test = temp_fcst_test_data, column = j , freq = 364, xreg_cols = temp_xreg_cols2)
```

When running `arima_fourier_train` or `arima_standard_train`, this is the error I am getting.

```
Residual standard error: 948600000 on 586 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.4815,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.4602 
F-statistic: 22.67 on 24 and 586 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16


 Fitting models using approximations to speed things up...

 ARIMA(2,1,2) with drift         : Inf
 ARIMA(0,1,0) with drift         : Inf
 ARIMA(1,1,0) with drift         : Inf
 ARIMA(0,1,1) with drift         : Inf
 ARIMA(0,1,0)                    : Inf
 ARIMA(1,1,2) with drift         : Inf
 ARIMA(2,1,1) with drift         : Inf
 ARIMA(3,1,2) with drift         : Inf
 ARIMA(2,1,3) with drift         : Inf
 ARIMA(1,1,1) with drift         : Inf
 ARIMA(1,1,3) with drift         : Inf
 ARIMA(3,1,1) with drift         : Inf
 ARIMA(3,1,3) with drift         : Inf
 ARIMA(2,1,2)                    : Inf

Error in auto.arima(y, xreg = xreg, seasonal = FALSE, max.d = 5, num.cores = 6,  : 
  No suitable ARIMA model found
[1] "this model will be ignored"
```

Is there a way how to improve hyper-parameters to get the forecast or the issue is something else? I am new to forcecasting and find it difficult to understand why the error.

If I am running SARIMA (i.e. seasonal parameter is set to TRUE) and this is the error I am getting:

```
Error in auto.arima(y, xreg = xreg, seasonal = TRUE, max.d = 5, num.cores = 6,  : 
  No suitable ARIMA model found
In addition: Warning message:
The chosen seasonal unit root test encountered an error when testing for the first difference.
From stl(): series is not periodic or has less than two periods
0 seasonal differences will be used. Consider using a different unit root test. 
[1] "this model will be ignored"
```

What are your thoughts? I am using also NNs and TBATS but the error is between 30% and 40%, I would like to have an error below 20%, or ideally below 15%.

Any help or advice is welcome!

### Thanks!

Comment: How did you split your data into train and test?

Comment: Please, define the value of  `j` in `column = j`

Comment: Added in question these details.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that the values in my variable are too large and are creating a numerical overflow. Hence I square rooted the values and I got the following error rates:

```
          model_name performance model_index
1  arima_fourier   0.1004043           1
2 arima_standard   0.1668806           2
3 arima_standard   0.2134641           3
4          naive   0.1978858           4
5         nnetar   0.1474986           5
6         nnetar   0.1758006           6
7         nnetar   0.1506708           7
8          tbats   0.2587426           8
```